# Asp.net redirect to another site

Tags: c#, asp.net, http-redirect

In our project we use MapPageRoute

```
public static class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
            settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
            routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);


            routes.IgnoreRoute("{*alljs}", new { allaspx = @".*\.js(/.*)?" });

            routes.MapPageRoute("Landing", "landing/{state}/{city}", "~/landing_test.aspx");
            routes.MapPageRoute("Cremation", "cremation-services", "~/cremations.aspx");
            routes.MapPageRoute("FAQ", "funeral-planning-faq", "~/FAQ.aspx");
            routes.MapPageRoute("Homes", "funeral-homes/{state}/{city}/{id}", "~/viewHome.aspx");
            routes.MapPageRoute("CitySearch", "search/{state}/{city}", "~/areaHomeLists.aspx");
            routes.MapPageRoute("BlankSearch", "search", "~/areaHomeLists.aspx");
            routes.MapPageRoute("About", "about", "~/about.aspx");
        }
    }
```

I need to redirect to another website with 301 code when user on About page.

I tried change MapPageRoute to MapRoute and I created RedirectController but it doesn't work for me (Or I don't understand how it works)

`routes.MapRoute("About", "about.aspx", new {controller = "Redirect", action = "FAQ"});`

```
public class RedirectController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Blog()
        {
            return RedirectPermanent("FAQ");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked RedirectToActionPermanent method? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoactionpermanent?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added rule to web.config and now it works

```
<rule name="About reditect" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="about*" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.google.com" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```